# How to test whether two generics have a base-subclass relationship without instantiating them?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following generic classes:

```
class Base<T> where T : ... { ... }
class Derived<T> : Base<T> where T : ... { ... }
class Another<T> where T : ... { ... }
class DerivedFromDerived<T> : Derived<T> where T : ... { ... }
```

Somewhere in my code, I would like to test whether a given generic inherits from `Base<T>`, without creating a particular instance of the generic. How do I do that?

```
static bool DerivedFromBase(Type type) { /* ??? */ }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase(typeof(Derived<>)));            // true
    Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase(typeof(Another<>)));            // false
    Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase(typeof(DerivedFromDerived<>))); // true
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Thank you Mark. Now I see the light. I originally tried the following:

```
typeof(Derived<>).BaseType == typeof(Base<>)
```

Apparently, this is correct. **But it is not.** The problem is that `Base`'s T is not the same thing as `Derived`'s T. So, in

```
typeof(Base<>)
```

`Base`'s `T` is a free type. But, in

```
typeof(Derived<>).BaseType
```

`Base`'s `T` is bound to `Derived`'s `T`, which is in turn a free type. (This is so awesome I would **LOVE** to see the `System.Reflection`'s source code!) Now,

```
typeof(Derived<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

unbounds `Base`'s `T`. Conclusion:

```
typeof(Derived<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Base<>)
```

And now, if you all excuse me, my head is burning.

Comment: I'm interested in answers here, because I *think* `Derived<int>` is not a subclass of `Base<long>`

Comment: @Matt Greer: Indeed, `Derived<int>` is not a subclass of `Base<long>`.

Comment: I think Mark has correctly answered your question, but I think you might mean something else as Matt has mentioned above. Could you clarify?

Comment: @B Tyler: I want to test whether a generic is derived from another generic, without having to plug in specific parameters. It should not be necessary to test whether `Derived<int>` is derived from `Base<int>`, only to later test whether `Derived<string>` is derived from `Base<string>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I think "IsAssignableFrom" will do the trick.

```
class Program
{
    class Base<T> { }
    class Derived<T> : Base<T> { }
    class Another<T> { }
    class DerivedFromDerived<T> : Derived<T> { }

    static bool DerivedFromBase<T>(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(Base<T>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase<int>(typeof(Derived<int>)));            // true    
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase<int>(typeof(Another<int>)));            // false    
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedFromBase<int>(typeof(DerivedFromDerived<int>))); // true   
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

To handle the open base type:

```
static bool DerivedFromBase(Type type)
    {
        Type openBase = typeof(Base<>);

        var baseType = type;

        while (baseType != typeof(Object) && baseType != null)
        {
            if (baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openBase) return true;

            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Though this might not be what you are looking for because you where dealing with open generic types in your original code typeof(Derived<>) as opposed to providing a concrete type for T.

Comment: I need that the function work on open generics. Otherwise... I'll have to rethink (and, most importantly, redo!) my work of about a week.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. Added a sample for open type testing. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this version, although it seems a little hacky.

```
private static bool IsDerivedFrom(Type derivedType, Type baseType)
{
    if (derivedType.BaseType == null)
        return false;

    if (derivedType.BaseType.GUID == baseType.GUID)
        return true;

    return IsDerivedFrom(derivedType.BaseType, baseType);
}
```

It relies on all types having different GUIDs, which should be true, but obviously a collision will happen next Thursday.

Comment: Why guid? Why not a direct comparison?