# Get inheritance tree of type

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To get parent class using Reflection on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/to-get-parent-class-using-reflection-on-c)

I am trying to find an easy way of getting the inheritance tree of a certain type using reflection in C#.

Let's say that I have the following classes;

```
public class A
{ }

public class B : A
{ }

public class C : B
{ }
```

How do I use reflection upon type 'C' to determine that its superclass is 'B', who in turn comes from 'A' and so on?  I know that I can use 'IsSubclassOf()', but let's assume that I don't know the superclass that I am looking for.

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/to-get-parent-class-using-reflection-on-c

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601486/how-to-test-whether-two-generics-have-a-base-subclass-relationship-without-instan

Comment: oh yeah, this is a dupe alright.  Guess I should have used 'parent' instead of 'superclass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting parent class' name using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/getting-parent-class-name-using-reflection)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get a type's immediate parent, you can use the [**`Type.BaseType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) property. You can iteratively call `BaseType` until it returns `null` to walk up a type's inheritance hierarchy.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInheritanceHierarchy
    (this Type type)
{
    for (var current = type; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
        yield return current;
}
```

Do note that it isn't valid to use `System.Object` as the end-point because not all types (for example, interface types) inherit from it.

Comment: Is it possible to walk the other direction?

Comment: @rolls, it is, but that would give you an entire tree, not a list.

Answer (score 3):

An object of type `System.Type` has a property named `BaseType` which returns "the type from which the current System.Type directly inherits." You can walk up this chain of `BaseType`s until you get `null`, at which point you know you have reached `System.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above... please find a simple set of routines

1. GetTree returns a period delimited list of subclasses, starting with the class passed in
2. The 3 overrides of XInheritsFromY( ) take a variable and then either a String, Type, or variable and returns true if X inherits from Y. (Crazy, right?)

Note that if you pass in a variable, X and Y may not have anything in common other than class structure.

Ex

```
mySubClassOfY X = new SubClassOfY();
myClassY  Y = new myClassY();

bool b = XInheritsFromY(X,Y)
```

b will be true even though they are different instances.

```
  public static string InheritanceTree(dynamic input_)
        {
            const string dlm = ".";
            Type t = null; 
            StringBuilder  rv  = new StringBuilder();

                t= input_.GetType();
            while (1==1)
            {
                if (null == t) break;
                rv.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", dlm, t.Name);
                t = t.BaseType;
            }
            return rv.ToString();
        }
        public static bool XInheritsFromY(dynamic X_, string Y_)
        {
            //pass in a string you are curious to see if is base of X_
            string tree = InheritanceTree(X_);
            Y_ = "." + Y_;
            return tree.Contains(Y_);
        }
        public static bool XInheritsFromY(dynamic X_, Type Y_)
        {
            //pass in a Type you are curious to see if is base of X_

            return XInheritsFromY(X_, Y_.Name);
        }
        public static bool XInheritsFromY(dynamic X_, dynamic Y_)
        {
            //pass in a variable you are curious to see if is base of X_
            // note this is just looking at classes
            // Y_ may not actually be same object as X_
            return XInheritsFromy(X_, Y_.GetType().Name);
        }
```

@Ani is correct in his comment that not all types inherit from System object.
The above code was originally written w/ System.Object and it tested correctly.
I changed those 5 parameters to dynamic and that also worked.
So if you are using c# 4.0 or greater, you can use dynamic and that should be all encompassing.

here is the test method...

```
[TestMethod]
        public void testInheritanceTree()
        {
            pgCashFlowMortgage m = new pgCashFlowMortgage();
            cashFlow cf = new cashFlow();
            string tree = tools.InheritanceTree(m);

            Assert.AreEqual(".pgCashFlowMortgage.cashFlow.pgBaseClass.sbBusObjBase.sbDatabaseObjBase.sbSimpleDatabaseObjBase.sbObjectBase.Object",tree);

            bool XifYyes = tools.XInheritsFromY(m, "cashFlow");
            Assert.IsTrue(XifYyes);

            XifYyes = tools.XInheritsFromY(m, cf.GetType());
            Assert.IsTrue(XifYyes);

            XifYyes = tools.XInheritsFromY(m, cf );
            Assert.IsTrue(XifYyes);

        }
```