# How to print out all the base type of an object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object, I would like to print out all its parent type up to the Object? How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "all it's base type"?

Comment: it has base type, base type has its own base type.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel he means all the base types in the inheritance heirarchy upto reaching the System.Object type

Comment: This should answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716896/get-inheritance-tree-of-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only interested in the *class* hierarchy:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
while (type != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    type = type.BaseType;
}
```

Comment: is type.Name same as type.ToString()?

Comment: @user705414: Quite possibly. I thought I'd be explicit :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, almost same... // System.Type
public override string ToString()
{
 return "Type: " + this.Name;
}

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = obj.GetType();

while (t != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
    t = t.BaseType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type currentType = obj.GetType();
while (currentType != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine(currentType.ToString());
  currentType = currentType.BaseType;
}
```