# How to get trace of properties tree?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, path, trace

lets say I have something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A A1 = new A();
        A1.B1.C1.GetPath();
    }
}

class A
{
    public B B1 { get; set; }
    public B B2 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public C C1 { get; set; }
}
class C
{
    public string GetPath();
}
```

Is there possibility to implement method `GetPath()`, that would return for example "`C1 in B1 in A1`" ?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716896/get-inheritance-tree-of-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to chieve this.

What you *can* do is:

- OOP way: define ctor where you pass parent/holder class reference, so it can be figured out at runtime.
- use of [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) and get just stack trace (don't know if this fits your needs actually)

Hope this helps.