# In C#, how could I get a class's inheritance distance to base class?

Tags: c#, subclass, distance

For example:
I have the following classes:

```
public class A {}
public class B:A {}
public class C:B {}
public class D:C {}
```

If there is a convenient method like to get a hierarchy distance to the base class(instead of testing D.IsSubclassOf(B)) to determine  if D is closer to A, or B is closer to A?

Comment: Its certainly possible, but why?  What would you need this for?

Comment: This might help you get the inheritance tree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716896/get-inheritance-tree-of-type . But again why would you want to do that ?

Comment: One way is to modify the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716896/get-inheritance-tree-of-type (code snippet in the answer) which should give you the value you need.

Comment: well, I'm developing a Unity game using C#, and we are using this project: https://github.com/lightszero/LSharp to make our game can hotfix  under IOS. So, this project analyze the dll and run it's explain the code in the dll. The problem is when it finding overloaded methods in dlls,  can not work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is of any help:

```
public static int? GetDegreeOfRelationship(Type typeA, Type typeB)
{
    if (typeA.IsInterface || typeB.IsInterface) return null; // interfaces are not part of the inheritance tree
    if (typeA == typeB) return 0;

    int distance = 0;
    Type child;
    if (typeA.IsAssignableFrom(typeB))
    {
        child = typeB;
        while ((child = child.BaseType) != typeA)
            distance--;
        return --distance;
    }
    else if(typeB.IsAssignableFrom(typeA))
    {
        child = typeA;
        while ((child = child.BaseType) != typeB)
            distance++;
        return ++distance;
    }
    else
       return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
int? distance = GetDegreeOfRelationship(typeof(A), typeof(D));      // -3
int? distance = GetDegreeOfRelationship(typeof(D), typeof(A));      //  3
int? distance = GetDegreeOfRelationship(typeof(B), typeof(B));      //  0
int? distance = GetDegreeOfRelationship(typeof(D), typeof(string)); // null
```

Comment: @simon: note that i've fixed an issue with interfaces, they are not part of the inheritance tree so i return null. Otherwise you run into a `NullReferenceException` since `IsAssignableFrom` returns `true` but you don't get to them via `BaseType`.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the code snipped suggested by @kha and adapted it for you, from this answer: [Get inheritance tree of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716896/get-inheritance-tree-of-type)

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInheritancHierarchy
        (this Type type)
    {
        for (var current = type; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
            yield return current;
    }
    public static int GetInheritanceDistance<TOther>(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInheritancHierarchy().TakeWhile(t => t != typeof(TOther)).Count();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var c = new C(); // 2
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().GetInheritanceDistance<A>());

var b = new B(); // 1
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().GetInheritanceDistance<A>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods to extend the behaviour of `Type` to iterate through the hierarchy to come up with distance to base or the path to base:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Form a = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().DistanceToBase());
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().PathToBase());
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static int DistanceToBase(this Type ob)
    {
        if (ob.BaseType == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else return 1 + ob.BaseType.DistanceToBase();
    }

    public static string PathToBase(this Type ob)
    {
        if (ob.BaseType == null)
        {
            return ob.Name;
        }
        return ob.Name + "->" + ob.BaseType.PathToBase();
    }
}
```