# Is there a way to determine all the possible types a variable could be?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a variable (of a particular type) that is in a NuGet package. The classes these variables are instances of inherit from numerous other classes and Interfaces. It seems like there would be a parent/child type of tree browser that describes or visualizes the inheritance tree of a type.

Is there a way to tell (at design time) what all those possibilities are? I think I could do a lot of clicking and chase these down one by one. It just seems like this would be a common enough problem that something exists for that.

I am trying to determine the most appropriate type to check for in in if statement or a switch statement.

Comment: types and sub-types can be defined on-the-fly at runtime, or could come from down-stream transient dependencies that you can't see directly

Comment: Closest thing is probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5716896/102937).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/scenario-change-your-design-using-visualization-and-modeling?view=vs-2019